# Scikit-learn pipeline for same data and steps fails to classifiy

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, text-classification, sklearn-pandas

I have vectors of floats that I created from doc2vec algorithm, and their labels. When i use them with a simple classifier, it works normally and gives an expected accuracy. Working code is below:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train_vecs #ndarray (20418,100)
#train_vecs = [[0.3244, 0.3232, -0.5454, 1.4543, ...],...]
y_train #labels
test_vecs #ndarray (6885,100)
y_test #labels

classifier = LinearSVC()
classifier.fit(train_vecs, y_train )
print('Test Accuracy: %.2f'%classifier.score(test_vecs, y_test))
```

However now I want to move it into a pipeline, because in the future I plan to do a feature union with different features. What I do is move the vectors into a dataframe, then use 2 custom transformers to i)select the column, ii) change the array type. Strangely the exact same data, with exact same shape, dtype and type.. gives 0.0005 accuracy. Which it does not make sense to me at all, it should give almost equal accuracy. After the ArrayCaster transformer the shapes and types of the inputs are exactly the same as before. The whole thing has been really frustrating.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

# transformer that picks a column from the dataframe
class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, column):
        self.column = column

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print('item selector type',type(X[self.column]))
        print('item selector shape',len(X[self.column]))
        print('item selector dtype',X[self.column].dtype)
        return (X[self.column])

# transformer that converts the series into an ndarray
class ArrayCaster(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data):
        print('array caster type',type(np.array(data.tolist())))
        print('array caster shape',np.array(data.tolist()).shape)
        print('array caster dtype',np.array(data.tolist()).dtype)
        return np.array(data.tolist())


train_vecs #ndarray (20418,100)
y_train #labels
test_vecs #ndarray (6885,100)
y_test #labels

train['vecs'] = pd.Series(train_vecs.tolist())
val['vecs'] = pd.Series(test_vecs.tolist())


classifier = Pipeline([
            ('selector', ItemSelector(column='vecs')),
            ('array', ArrayCaster()),
            ('clf',LinearSVC())])

classifier.fit(train, y_train)
print('Test Accuracy: %.2f'%classifier.score(test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry about that.. I figured it out. The error is pretty annoying to notice. All I had to do is cast them as list and place them into the dataframe, instead of converting them to series.
Change this

```
train['vecs'] = pd.Series(train_vecs.tolist())
val['vecs'] = pd.Series(test_vecs.tolist())
```

into:

```
train['vecs'] = list(train_vecs)
val['vecs'] = list(test_vecs)
```